# Is it possible to put range in different manners in for loop?

Tags: python

I have a Dataset with 610 data-samples with labeled numbers from 1 to 610.

Therefore I gave iteration) for i in range (1,610):

But after 286 iterations it was stopped because data-Sample 287 was missed.
And then I saw again all Data manually, then I know, that there is datasample number 287,291,292 are missing.

However I want to load and run my data-samples through for loop.

is there any possible solutions to do that?

Thanks in advance.

```
for i in range(1,610):    
    trueData = np.load(path_load + 'featureMatrixTrue_of_K1_%d.npy' % i)

    output = []
    for c in range(2,6):

        interp = scipy.interpolate.griddata((trueData[:,0],trueData[:,1]), trueData[:,c], (X.flatten(),Y.flatten()))   
        interp = interp.reshape(num_points, -1)  
        if c==5:
            interp = np.logical_and(np.where(interp < 0.92,0,1), np.where(interp > 1.06,0,1))
            #interp = interp.astype(int)
        output.append(interp)
    output = np.array(output)
```

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far

Comment: Can you do a try/except block when you index using `i` so that the loop doesn't stop but rather you can just get a message that warns about missing data at whatever `i` was?

Comment: Please provide a sample of the dataset and how are you accessing the said dataset, would help a lot to understand your problem

Comment: How do you actually access the data samples with `i`? Also would be great to include what you've done so far.

Comment: try to provide some code on what you have done and look at itertools

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hard-coding a skip for 287, 291, and 292, you should gracefully allow the for loop to continue if data is missing. Also, range should be `range(1,611)` if your indexes go from 1 to 610 inclusive.

```
data = {1:'lorum', 2:'ipsum', 4: 'dolor'}

for i in range(1, 5):
    try:
        print(data[i])
    except KeyError:
        print('Data missing at',i)
```

Output:

```
lorum
ipsum
Data missing at 3
dolor
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking if the file exists first before trying to load it. `os.path` should be helpful in your case, specifically `isfile()`

```
import os.path

for i in range(1,610):
    data_set_path = path_load + 'featureMatrixTrue_of_K1_%d.npy' % i
    # Check if file does not exist,
    # if its missing we proceed to the next value of i
    if not os.path.isfile(data_set_path):
        continue
    trueData = np.load(data_set_path)

    output = []
    for c in range(2,6):

        interp = scipy.interpolate.griddata((trueData[:,0],trueData[:,1]), trueData[:,c], (X.flatten(),Y.flatten()))   
        interp = interp.reshape(num_points, -1)  
        if c==5:
            interp = np.logical_and(np.where(interp < 0.92,0,1), np.where(interp > 1.06,0,1))
            #interp = interp.astype(int)
        output.append(interp)
    output = np.array(output)
```